# What is the 'AttachInfo' about? I use MAT tool get it

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I use the MAT tool to check my application memory, it return information is 
" One instance of "android.view.View$AttachInfo" loaded by "" occupies 9,473,472 (52.82%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "android.view.View$AttachInfo" loaded by ""."

What is the 'AttachInfo' about? How could I check my code for the question?
And there is another question, it's 
" 28 instances of "com.tieto.mytimehourentry.custom.WheelPickerScrollView", loaded by "dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x4051c520" occupy 2,301,152 (12.83%) bytes. These instances are referenced from one instance of "java.lang.Object[]", loaded by "" "

How can I release the didn't used View object? Are they must be released by OS?

Comment: The problem is maybe about Gallery. Why some one advice to me use ViewPage instead of Gallery.